# Comportamiento diferente según navegador con css transform

Tags: css, html5, css3

Estoy intentando realizar unas animaciones pero me encuentro con que la animación para Chrome y Firefox no hacen lo mismo, en Chrome la animación funciona pero con el movimiento invertido a lo que hace con el resto de navegadores.

Éste es el código (también disponible en [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/705fy2xm/2/)):

```js
(function() {
  animation0();
})();

var where = "";
window.setInterval(function() {
  startAnimation();
}, 1000);
var x = 0;

function startAnimation(elem) {
  if (x == 0) {
    animation1();
  } else if (x == 1) {
    // comentado para evitar error innecesario
    //animation3();
  }
  x++;
}

function animation0() {
  var esq1 = document.getElementById('esq1');
  var esq2 = document.getElementById('esq2');
  esq1.style.backgroundColor = "#bd9559";
  esq1.style.zIndex = "15";
  esq2.style.backgroundColor = "#0b4242";
  esq2.style.zIndex = "14";

  console.log("animation0");
}

function animation1() {
  where = 1;
  var esq1 = document.getElementById('esq1');
  var esq2 = document.getElementById('esq2');
  var dre1 = document.getElementById('dre1');
  var dre2 = document.getElementById('dre2');
  esq1.style.zIndex = "15";

  esq2.style.transition = "transform 1s ease-in";
  esq2.style.webkitTransition = "transform 1s ease-in"; //Chrome
  esq2.style.MozTransition = "transform 1s ease-in"; //Firefox
  esq2.style.msTransition = "transform 1s ease-in";
  esq2.style.OTransition = "transform 1s ease-in";

  esq2.style.transform = "matrix(-1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -" + window.innerWidth + ")";
  esq2.style.webkitTransform = "matrix(-1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -" + window.innerWidth + ")";
  esq2.style.MozTransform = "matrix(-1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -" + window.innerWidth + ")";
  esq2.style.msTransform = "matrix(-1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -" + window.innerWidth + ")";
  esq2.style.OTransform = "matrix(-1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -" + window.innerWidth + ")";

  esq2.style.zIndex = "14";

  dre2.style.zIndex = "13";
  dre1.style.zIndex = "-1";
  dre1.style.transition = "transform 0.6s ease-in";

  dre1.style.transform = "matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -" + window.innerWidth + ")";

  esq2.addEventListener("transitionend", function(event) {
    animation2();
  }, false);
}

function animation2() {
  var esq1 = document.getElementById('esq1');
  var esq2 = document.getElementById('esq2');
  var dre1 = document.getElementById('dre1');
  esq1.style.zIndex = "13";
  esq2.style.zIndex = "15";
  dre1.style.zIndex = "12";

  esq1.style.transition = "transform 0.5s ease-out";
  esq1.style.transform = "matrix(-1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -" + window.innerWidth + ")";
}

$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
  if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
    where = where - 1;
  } else {
    where = where + 1;
  }
  var funcionexist = "window.animation" + where + "()";
  if (typeof funcionexist !== 'undefined') {
    console.log("la func existeix: " + funcionexist);
    window.funcionexist;
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden
}

svg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 1003
}

.base_layout {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.base_panel {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200vw;
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

.panel-left {
  transform-origin: right center;
  right: 50%;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}

.panel-right {
  transform-origin: left center;
  left: 50%;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}

#esq1 {
  transform-origin: right center;
  right: 50%;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

#esq2 {
  transition: transform 0.8s ease-in;
}

#dre1 {
  background-image: url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-1EjZEV0gPfQ/VDmI-6gW83I/AAAAAAAAAEE/WhJUacJZ7ko/w1200-h1400/All%2Byou%2Bneed%2Bis%2Blove.png");
  background-size: 50%;
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 12;
}

#dre2 {
  background-image: url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-1EjZEV0gPfQ/VDmI-6gW83I/AAAAAAAAAEE/WhJUacJZ7ko/w1200-h1400/All%2Byou%2Bneed%2Bis%2Blove.png");
  background-size: 50%;
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 13;
}

.w-xs-100 {
  width: 100%;
}

.h-xs-100 {
  height: 100%;
}

.textslide {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="base_layout">
  <div class="base_panel panel-left" id="esq1"></div>
  <div class="base_panel panel-left" id="esq2"></div>
  <div class="base_panel panel-right" id="dre1"></div>
  <div class="base_panel panel-right" id="dre2"></div>
</div>
```

En Firefox, IE gira en sentido horario. En Chrome gira en sentido antihorario.

Comment: Sucede exactamente igual con Opera (giro antihorario) para que también lo tengas en cuenta

Comment: Gracias @Huskie , no lo tenía en cuenta.

Answer (score 0):

El problema parece que está en que los navegadores inicializan los valores por defecto a cosas diferentes y eso hace que la animación se vea en direcciones diferentes (porque estás definiendo la animación con un punto de destino, pero no hay un punto de inicio definido).

Entonces una posible solución sería definir un punto de partida que sea el mismo para todos los navegadores (algo que puedes hacer en CSS o JS). De ese modo, la animación se debería ver en la misma dirección.

Con ese cambio, ya se ve igual en Chrome, Firefox, Opera, IE y Edge:

```js
(function() {
  animation0();
})();

var where = "";
window.setInterval(function() {
  startAnimation();
}, 1000);
var x = 0;

/* definir valores iniciales para esq1 y esq2 */
var esq1 = document.getElementById('esq1');
esq1.style.transform = "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -" + window.innerWidth + ")";
var esq2 = document.getElementById('esq2');
esq2.style.transform = "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -" + window.innerWidth + ")";
esq2.style.webkitTransform = "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -" + window.innerWidth + ")";
esq2.style.MozTransform = "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -" + window.innerWidth + ")";
esq2.style.msTransform = "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -" + window.innerWidth + ")";
esq2.style.OTransform = "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -" + window.innerWidth + ")";


function startAnimation(elem) {
  if (x == 0) {
    animation1();
  } else if (x == 1) {
    // comentado para evitar error innecesario
    //animation3();
  }
  x++;
}

function animation0() {
  var esq1 = document.getElementById('esq1');
  var esq2 = document.getElementById('esq2');
  esq1.style.backgroundColor = "#bd9559";
  esq1.style.zIndex = "15";
  esq2.style.backgroundColor = "#0b4242";
  esq2.style.zIndex = "14";

  console.log("animation0");
}

function animation1() {
  where = 1;
  var esq1 = document.getElementById('esq1');
  var esq2 = document.getElementById('esq2');
  var dre1 = document.getElementById('dre1');
  var dre2 = document.getElementById('dre2');
  esq1.style.zIndex = "15";

  esq2.style.transition = "transform 1s ease-in";
  esq2.style.webkitTransition = "transform 1s ease-in"; //Chrome
  esq2.style.MozTransition = "transform 1s ease-in"; //Firefox
  esq2.style.msTransition = "transform 1s ease-in";
  esq2.style.OTransition = "transform 1s ease-in";

  esq2.style.transform = "matrix(-1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -" + window.innerWidth + ")";
  esq2.style.webkitTransform = "matrix(-1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -" + window.innerWidth + ")";
  esq2.style.MozTransform = "matrix(-1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -" + window.innerWidth + ")";
  esq2.style.msTransform = "matrix(-1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -" + window.innerWidth + ")";
  esq2.style.OTransform = "matrix(-1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -" + window.innerWidth + ")";

  esq2.style.zIndex = "14";

  dre2.style.zIndex = "13";
  dre1.style.zIndex = "-1";
  dre1.style.transition = "transform 0.6s ease-in";

  dre1.style.transform = "matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -" + window.innerWidth + ")";

  esq2.addEventListener("transitionend", function(event) {
    animation2();
  }, false);
}

function animation2() {

  var esq1 = document.getElementById('esq1');
  var esq2 = document.getElementById('esq2');
  var dre1 = document.getElementById('dre1');
  esq1.style.zIndex = "13";
  esq2.style.zIndex = "15";
  dre1.style.zIndex = "12";

  esq1.style.transition = "transform 0.5s ease-out";
  esq1.style.transform = "matrix(-1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -" + window.innerWidth + ")";
}

$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
  if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
    where = where - 1;
  } else {
    where = where + 1;
  }
  var funcionexist = "window.animation" + where + "()";
  if (typeof funcionexist !== 'undefined') {
    console.log("la func existeix: " + funcionexist);
    window.funcionexist;
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden
}

svg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 1003
}

.base_layout {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.base_panel {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200vw;
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

.panel-left {
  transform-origin: right center;
  right: 50%;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}

.panel-right {
  transform-origin: left center;
  left: 50%;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}

#esq1 {
  transform-origin: right center;
  right: 50%;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

#esq2 {
  transition: transform 0.8s ease-in;
}

#dre1 {
  background-image: url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-1EjZEV0gPfQ/VDmI-6gW83I/AAAAAAAAAEE/WhJUacJZ7ko/w1200-h1400/All%2Byou%2Bneed%2Bis%2Blove.png");
  background-size: 50%;
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 12;
}

#dre2 {
  background-image: url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-1EjZEV0gPfQ/VDmI-6gW83I/AAAAAAAAAEE/WhJUacJZ7ko/w1200-h1400/All%2Byou%2Bneed%2Bis%2Blove.png");
  background-size: 50%;
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 13;
}

.w-xs-100 {
  width: 100%;
}

.h-xs-100 {
  height: 100%;
}

.textslide {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="base_layout">
  <div class="base_panel panel-left" id="esq1"></div>
  <div class="base_panel panel-left" id="esq2"></div>
  <div class="base_panel panel-right" id="dre1"></div>
  <div class="base_panel panel-right" id="dre2"></div>
</div>
```